# Proving that a subset is compact in $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, compactness, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I have posted a related question earlier but like to make the question more specific now so that one may help point out any mistake I possibly make.

Consider the following two subsets in $L^2(0,1)$:

${\cal H}:= \{g \in L^2(0,1) \;|\; g:\text{non-decreasing}\}$
$ {\cal G}:=\{ g \in L^2(0,1) \;|\; g:\text{non-decreasing}, \int_0^1 g(\alpha)d\alpha = c_1, \int_0^1 g^2(\alpha)d\alpha=c_2\}$,
where $c_1\in \Re$ and $c_2>0$ are some fixed values and are chosen such that the set ${\cal G}$ is nonempty.

Obviously, ${\cal G} \subseteq {\cal H}$.

I claim that $cl({\cal G})$ is weakly compact and $cl({\cal G}) \subseteq {\cal H}$ where $cl()$ referes to the closure of the set.

My reasoning is based on the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, which states that 
"Let $X$ be the dual to some separable Banach space $Z$, $X = Z^*$. Then any bounded subset $M$ of $X$ is precompact in the weak-* topology, i.e. any sequence in $M$ has a weak-* convergent subsequence"

Given that any element in ${\cal G}$ is bounded by $\sqrt{c_2}$, we may apply the above theorem to conclude that ${\cal G}$ is weakly precompact, which by definition leads to $cl({\cal G})$ is weakly compact.

Since any sequence in ${\cal G}$ will always converge to a non-decreasing function, i.e. the limit points are in ${\cal H}$, we can conclude that the closure $cl({\cal G}) \subseteq {\cal H}$.

I just like to check if there is anything I might overlook in the above argument. Thanks for pointing out if any!

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "$g$ non decreasing" for elements of the Hilbert space $L^2(0,1)$, which are not functions in the strict sense but equivalence-classes of functions? In particular, we can change any non-decreasing function on a set of measure zero so that it will not be non-decreasing, so - are your sets really well defined?

Comment: Indeed I need to be careful here. but non-decreasing a.e. should work also.

Comment: @uniquesolution On the one hand you make a valid point. On the other hand, it's a very standard abuse of language. People say for example that $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^2([0,1])$. That entails that $C$ is a _subset_ of $L^2$, which is not literally true. If $C$ is a subset of $L^2$ then some elements of $L^2$ are "continuous" and some are not. When people  say that $f\in L^2$ is continuous that's just shorthand for saying that there exists a contiinuous $g$ with $f=g$ ae. Same for "non-decreasing".

Comment: @JOR Indeed you need to be careful. Saying "non-decreasing ae" makes very little sense as far as I can see. See my other comment for what you really mean to say. Meanwhile, note that "continuous ae" does make perfect sense, but EXERCISE: Show that (i) does not imply (ii) and (ii) does not imply (i), for $f\in L^2([0,1])$: (i) $f$ is continuous ae, (ii) there exists a continuous function $g$ with $f=g$ ae. Note that it's (ii) that people mean when they talk about a "continuous" $f\in L^2$. Similarly for "non-decreasing", except that "non-decreasing ae" is actually meaningless.

Comment: One way to say this: $h\in\mathcal{H}$ is "non-decreasing" if the equivalence class $h$ contains a non-decreasing function on $[0,1]$. If there are two such elements in the equivalence class, then the two must agree at the points of continuity of either. The only place they could disagree is at points of discontinuity, which is a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ because such a set is at most countable. So it is reasonable to talk about non-decreasing functions in $L^2[0,1]$, with that understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok but you should give some details on the fact that $\mathrm{cl}(G)\subset H$. That is, you should prove that the weak limit of a sequence of nondecreasing functions is nondecreasing.

First of all, we deal here with equivalence classes up to almost everywhere (a.e.) equivalence, so the nondecreasing assumption is to be interpreted as holding up to an exceptional null set. This is conveniently characterized in integral form as follows: 
$$
f\text{ is "a.e. nondecreasing" }\ \Leftrightarrow \ \int f\left( -\frac{d\phi}{dx} \right)\, dx \ge 0 \quad \forall \phi\in C^\infty_c,\, \phi \ge 0.$$
Here $C^\infty_c$ denotes smooth functions with compact support in $(0,1)$ (so in particular, functions that vanish at $0$, $1$).

You can now show that this "a.e. nondecreasing" condition is preserved by weak limits. By the way, the condition $\int f\, dx = c_1$ is also preserved by weak limits. The condition on the norm, on the other hand, is only partially preserved, as the norm of a weak limit can be strictly lower than the norm of the terms of the sequence. Summing up, you get that
$$
\mathrm{cl}(G)\subset \left\{ f\in L^2(0,1),\ f \text{ is a.e. nondecreasing},\ \int f\, dx=c_1,\ \int f^2\, dx \le c_2 \right\}.$$

Comment: Many thanks for all the clarifications! this certainly helps.

Comment: I am now a bit confused about how you would show the weak convergence to non-decreasing function using the characterization you proposed. Would you mind elaborate a bit on that? Wouldn't the argument using strong convergence also works which then implies the weak convergence must hold?

Comment: If the sequence $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ then the integral $\int f_n \phi'$ converges to $\int f \phi'$. So if all $f_n$ are ae nondecreasing then $f$ is also nondecreasing

Comment: Thanks! I misread your notation so that I got confused. But it's obvious now.

Comment: @JOR: If this answer was useful, would you consider [accepting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)? Thanks